# Hibernate criteria MAX of SUM

Tags: java, hibernate, hql, criteria

How can I achieve this HQL with criteria (JAVA)

```
"SELECT MAX(pointsum) FROM (SELECT SUM(h.point) as pointsum FROM HealthPoint h WHERE h.player.partner = :partner GROUP BY h.player)"
```

I already test this but I got that but i got property `pointsum` not found

```
DetachedCriteria detachedPlayer = DetachedCriteria.forClass(Player.class);
detachedPlayer.add(Restrictions.eq("partner", partner));
detachedPlayer.setProjection(Projections.property("id"));

Criteria criteria = getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession().createCriteria(HealthPoint.class);
criteria.add(Subqueries.propertyIn("player", detachedPlayer));
ProjectionList proj = Projections.projectionList();
proj.add(Projections.sum("point"));
proj.add(Projections.groupProperty("player"));
criteria.setProjection(Projections.alias(proj, "pointsum"));
criteria.setProjection(Projections.max("pointsum"));
return (Integer) criteria.uniqueResult();
```

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### No supported in hql

Subqueries in the from clause may not be possible in hql.
see https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/core.old/reference/en/html/queryhql-subqueries.html

> Note that HQL subqueries may occur only in the select or where
> clauses.

---

### Other options

I have two suggestions to resolve this: order and limit the results, or create a view.

1. Limit the results to the one you want:

   ```
   .createQuery("SELECT SUM(h.point) as pointsum FROM HealthPoint h WHERE h.player.partner = :partner GROUP BY h.player order by pointsum desc")
   .limit(1);
   ```
2. Create a view in the database and select from that

   ```
   create view HealthPointSumsByPlayer 
   as 
     select sum(point), player_id 
     from Health_Points 
     group by player_id;
   ```

Then select (via hql) from that.

Comment: Option 1 solve the problem even if I dont like it very much because it is not really a MAX function but give the same result! NB: there is not .limit(..) but .maxResult(..).

Thank you @Andreas!